# What's the different betweet function vs. function()?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Maybe my question appears stupid for you... Unfortunately, I didn't find an answer in the tutorials about callbacks. Please help me.

I would like to figure out what is the different between

1.)

```
function name ( input, cb )
```

and

2.)

```
function name ( input, cb() )
```

by

```
cb() {
...
}
```

What do produce the brackets in example 2.)? I guess, it has something to do with synchrone / asynchrone javascript. Please help me to understand the consequences.

That's my unworking code:

```
if(T.get('statuses/show/' + tweet.id_str, { include_my_retweet:true }, iRT) === true){ //iRT = I have retweeted
   console.log('Not retweeted. ');
}
```

That's my working code:

```
if(T.get('statuses/show/' + tweet.id_str, { include_my_retweet:true }, iRT()) === true){  //iRT = I have retweeted
console.log('Not retweeted. ');
}
```

And this is my return function:

```
return( noRetweet() );  


function noRetweet() {
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you show more complete examples?  I don't understand your examples.  Are you trying to *create* or *call* the `name()` function?

Comment: The second one is a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear if what you are trying to do is function call or function definition.

**Function call**

If it is a function call the `function` keyword should not be here. A function `f` is called just like this: `f(arg)`;

In the first case, the function `name` gets as second argument the function `cb`. It can then call back this function – or do whatever it wants with it – whenever it wants.

In the second case, you directly call `cb` first (that what the `()` are for, you could also have call it with arguments, i.e. `name(input, cb(arg))`) and the result of this call (not the function itself) is passed as second argument to `name`.

```
name(input, cb());
```

is roughly equivalent to:

```
var tmpResult = cb();
name(input, tmpResult);
```

**Function definition**

If it is function definitions, the bodies of the functions are missing. A function is defined like this.

```
 function f(arg){
   // What happens when the function is called.
 }
```

In this case, the second case is just invalid. It is a syntax error and does not mean anything.

**EDIT**

Following your addition to the question, your `if` should work just fine. If it is `true` or not actually depends of the result of the `T.get` function. As I said earlier, in the first case you are giving `T.get` the function `iRT`, in the second case its result. You should look at what is exactly expecting `T.get` and providing it with the proper argument (I suspect it is the result of `iRT`, but without knowing what these functions do, we can only guess).

Comment: The second case is a syntax error...

Comment: Thanks Roque. I try to write a if condition that starts, if the cb was delivered. But my if condition only works with cb(). I feel, that's not correct...

Comment: @FelixKling I assumed op was trying to do a function call. However, it is actually quite unclear what he is trying to do. I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Roque, that's what I would expect to. But it only works with iRT()... And that is wrong in meaning of syntax.

Comment: No it is not. It just means you are calling `iRT` first and provides its result to `T.get`.

Comment: Does that mean, that my if condition will only become true, when iRT() returns true?

Comment: No. It means that it will be accepted when `T.get` returns `true`. The results of `T.get` most likely depends of its arguments though. Hence, indirectly, it probably depends of the results of `iRT` (which is provided as an argument for `T.get`). But the `if` instruction only sees the result of `T.get` in your code.

Comment: ok, that means, I wrote the wrong code to check if I have already retweeted a tweet before I try to retweet it. right?

Comment: @NewbieXXL: I'm pretty sure `T.get` is asynchronous.

Comment: @NewbieXXL without knowing what `T.get` does and how it works, we cannot answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

The general idea is that **when you call your function** your parameters can be whatever they want as long as they produce the result. However, when you define your function, the parameter must be a variable.

Below, you can see that I define each function with separate parameters, but when I call it, I'm allowed to use `add()` as a parameter because it will produce a result that can be used as a parameter for `getNumbers()`.

```js
function add (x1, x2) {
  return x1 + x2;
}

function getNumbers (x3, x4) {
  return x3 + x4;
}

document.getElementById("math").innerHTML = getNumbers(3, add(1,2));
```

```html
<div id="math"></div>
```